# Flutter - Render new Widgets on click

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

The title basically says it all. A very nooby question... I have this basic code to create the initial state of my app :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Some title'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(config.title)),
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          new InputWidget(),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, how can I render a new Widget when the user clicks on a button? Let's say I want to instantiate another InputWidget.

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly...

I think the main point is that you should not think of "another" widget - if you change the content of `MyHomePage` from having first one child and then two you don't really *keep* the first child and then *add another* child. You simply first say "I want one child" and then you change your mind and say "I want two children".

In your code you do this by calling `setState` inside `_MyHomePageState`. Flutter takes care of keeping the first and adding the second child.

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Some title'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = new List.generate(count, (int i) => new InputWidget(i));

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(widget.title)),
        body: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: children
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count = count + 1;
            });
          },
        )
    );
  }
}

class InputWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final int index;

  InputWidget(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text("InputWidget: " + index.toString());
  }
}
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: So, is this the way the user can navigate between pages by clicking buttons or is there another approach for this?

Comment: I think for this you should look into the `onGenerateRoute` property of `MaterialApp` - the gallery example app in the repository has some examples. But I am very new to Flutter, too!

Comment: I'll open up a new thread, going to let you know as soon as I find out. thanks :)

Comment: Perfect Answer Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Your build function is "just code", so you can build the array you pass to the column dynamically, using something like

```
var children = [];
children.add(new InputWidget());
if (_showAnother)
  children.add(new InputWidget());
...
  body: new Column(
    ...
    children: children,
...
```

...where `_showAnother` is some sort of bool field that you set when the button is tapped.

Comment: Understod, but it shows this error while trying the above code::

error:: 
Type 'List<dynamic>' should be 'List<Widget>' to implement expected type 'List<Widget>'

The solution for the above error :  instead of defining the node name as a variable that will be List<Widget>